# Regex for two characters

Tags: c#, regex

How to construct a `Regex` to allow enter `CA` or `CH`?
Tried `\bC(A|H)` and `C(A|H)` but I need to validate it in the `KeyPress` event of the `textbox` like this;

```
private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"C(A|H)");

private void txtCaCh_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        return;

    if (!_rolfRegex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper()))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: How can you match a string consisting of multiple characters when you have a function that gets called with one character? You need to aggretate the characters, then try to match them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should post this as answer

Comment: I added my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
if (e.KeyChar != (char)8)  // Not a backspace key
   if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtCaCh.Text.ToUpper() + e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper(), @"^C[AH]?$"))  // If the value is not CH or CA
       e.Handled = true;   // Do not let it pass
```

Inside the `KeyPress` event handler, `txtCaCh.Text` contains the value before adding the next key. So, to get the full value we need to add the newly pressed key value. After that, we can check if the value is the one we can accept.

```
^C[AH]?$
```

This regex accepts `C` or `CA` or `CH` values, so that we can type them in.

Then, you need to validate it at some other event  with `^C[AH]$` (`Leave` event, for example).

**Live validation** cannot be performed at the same time as **final validation**.

Answer (score 2):

instead of validating the `e.KeyChar`, validate the content of the control itself:

```
if(!_rolfRegex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox)?.Value.ToUpper())
    e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: In `KeyPress` event `txtBox.Text `returns what is in the `textbox` not with the char I just entered.

Comment: This syntax is not for .net 4 which I'm using. It's Roslyn right?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern must be `^C[AH]$`. Start of input (**^**), folowing C, then A or H (**[AH]**)and end of input (**$**).

```
private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^C[AH]$");

private void txtCaCh_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        return;

    var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (txtBox.Text != null && _rolfRegex.IsMatch(txtBox.Text.ToUpper()))
    {
        // TODO now we have match, handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but `e.KeyChar` is a *single character*.

Comment: @Irshad:  You need to get text from sender (which is TextBox). I edited my answer.

Comment: In `KeyPress` event `txtBox.Text` retruns what is in the `textbox` not with the char I entered.